# How to execute function stored in variable / var x="function(){alert('a')}"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I do this is javascipt

```
var x = 'function(){ ... }'
x = x.toFunction();
x();
```

for example I have been using `var x = '...'; eval(x)` but I read that this is bad and slow.

In case it helps what I'm trying to accomplish is to run a function that is passed as an attribute to `<loaded>` For example:

***HTML***

```
 <p loaded="test, function(){alert('it worked!')}">
```

***AngularJS***

```
.directive('loaded', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
   var paramOne = attr.loaded.substr(0, attr.loaded.indexOf(',')) //paramOne = test
   var paramTwo = attr.loaded.substr(paramOne.length+1).trim() //paramTwo = "function(){alert('it worked!')"
   if (paramOne==='test') paramTwo() //This is where I use to use eval(paramTwo)
  }
 }
})
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leathan/uzsj3wLb/3/).

***EDIT: *** I am not posting this as an answer because Im not yet sure.. I might be doing everything wrong.

```
var x = "function(){alert('it worked!')";
x = new Function('(' + x + ')()');
x(); //alerts 'it worked!'
```

Please let me know if my edit is a viable answer or if I should follow an entirely new approach

Comment: Eval is bad because storing code in a string is generally avoidable, and creates security risks with XSS. I suggest you find a better way to encode functionality than using a string. Functions belong in JS files.

Comment: Take a look at isolate scope binding (&) for directives in AngularJS. The “&” operator allows you to invoke or evaluate an expression on the parent scope of whatever the directive is inside of.

Comment: @eduardo_melo what you said really confused me :/ do you think you can pass me a direct link where I can read about that?

Comment: @banned_leathan [AngularJS - Isolate Scope "&"](https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am)

Comment: I will go spend my time on that link now, thanks eduardo, can you check my edit and tell me if thats still a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this code, but I think that's the idea:

```
.directive('loaded', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
     fn: '&'
    }
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var paramOne = attr.param1;

      if (paramOne === 'test'){
        scope.fn();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

`fn` is the function that you want to be executed inside the link function. You can define this function inside the controller. `param1` is a parameter you should pass in another attribute (in that case, the value of this attribute would be 'test').

```
<p loaded param1='test' fn='fn()'>
```

Comment: I was about to come back and say your comment + link was EXACTLY what i needed to figure out the answer! ! !